# add option to select tag for EntityType field before creating the form

Tags: php, forms, symfony

I have a form containing two EntityType fields, first one is category and the second is subCategory, the category field will have all the categories that i have in the database, but i want to add one more to these, which is "all categories", and i want it to be the one selected by default, how can i achieve this..

```
$builder
            ->add(
                'category',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'Catégorie',
                    'class' => Category::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'title',
                    'mapped' => false
                ]
            )

            ->add(
                'subCategory',
                EntityType::class,
                [
                    'label' => 'Sous-catégorie',
                    'class' => SubCategory::class,
                    'choice_label' => 'title',
                    'mapped' => false
                ]
            );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct your array of choices manually and use [`ChoiceType`](https://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/choice.html), for example:

```
// retrieve list of your categories in your controller or somewhere else
// and pass it using the options. Add it also before the default option "All categories".
$categories = $options['categories'];

$builder->add('category', ChoiceType::class, [
    'choices' => $categories,
    ...
```